# Facebook Actionscript and IE

Tags: actionscript-3, internet-explorer, actionscript, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Facebook Actionscript graph api but I seem to be having problems in IE (other browsers like chrome and firefox seem okay so far).

From what i can tell, it's logging in fine and returning the user id but when i do a lookup on that user with Facebook.api(_user, handleUserRequest); I get an error.

Is there any known problems with the Facebook Actionscript graph api that affects IE only?

thanks
ob

Per request - the error is as follows:

```
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://graph.facebook.com/100002210990429?access%5Ftoken=205690086123032%7C2%2EUzvN3mFr07kPAecZ7qN1Rg%5F%5F%2E3600%2E1303135200%2E1%2D100002210990429%7Cz9L%5Fc26QKCc6cs2g5FClG%5FBsoZg"]
```

This if this url is pasted into chrome it works just fine, but IE returns 'unable to download XXXXXXXX from graph.facebook.com'

best
obie

the code that I'm using is as follows:

```
package com.client.facebookgame.services 
{

    import com.client.facebookgame.services.events.FacebookServiceEvent;
    import com.facebook.graph.data.FacebookSession;
    import com.facebook.graph.Facebook;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import uk.co.thereceptacle.utils.Debug;

    /**
     * Facebook Service
     */
    public class FacebookService extends EventDispatcher
    {
        // constants
        public static const API_KEY             : String = "XXXXXX";
        public static const PERMISSIONS         : String = "read_stream,publish_stream,user_likes";
        public static const FB_REDIRECT_URL     : String = "http://apps.facebook.com/appname/";
        public static const LOGGED_IN           : String = "loggedin";
        public static const LOGGED_IN_ON_FB     : String = "loggedinonfacebook";
        public static const LOGGED_OUT          : String = "loggedout";
        public static const LOGGED_OUT_ON_FB    : String = "loggedoutonfacebook";

        public static const TIMEOUT_COUNT       : int = 10;
        public static const TIMER_DELAY         : int = 3 * 1000;


        // properties
        private var _user           : String;
        private var _topUrl         : String;
        private var _currentState   : String;
        private var _timer          : Timer;
        private var _timerCount     : int;

        public var postObject       : Object;


        // constuctor
        public function FacebookService() 
        {
            if (ExternalInterface.available) _topUrl = ExternalInterface.call("top.location.toString");
            Debug.log("facebook init", this);
            Facebook.init(API_KEY, handleLogin);

            startTiming();

            currentState = _topUrl ? LOGGED_OUT : LOGGED_OUT_ON_FB;
        }




        // methods
        public function login():void
        {
            Facebook.login(handleLogin, { perms: PERMISSIONS } );
        }

        public function logout():void
        {
            Facebook.logout(handleLogout);
        }

        public function selectUserFriendsWithAppRequestDialogue(message:String, dialogueType:String = "iframe", optionalPostObject:Object = null):void
        {
            this.postObject = optionalPostObject;
            Facebook.ui("apprequests", { message:message }, handleAppRequest, dialogueType);
        }

        public function checkIfUserLikesApp():void
        {
            Facebook.api(_user + "/likes", handleLikes);
        }

        private function startTiming():void
        {
            if (_timer) clearTimer();
            _timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, TIMEOUT_COUNT);
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTimerEvents);
            _timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, handleTimerEvents);
            _timer.start();
        }

        private function clearTimer():void
        {
            _timer.stop();
            _timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleTimerEvents);
            _timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, handleTimerEvents);
            _timer = null;

            _timerCount = 0;
        }

        // event handlers
        private function handleLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            if (_timer) clearTimer();

            if (success)
            {
                Debug.log(success, this);
                _user = success.uid;

                currentState = _topUrl ? LOGGED_IN : LOGGED_IN_ON_FB;

                Facebook.api("/" + _user, handleGetUser);
            }
            else if (!success && !_topUrl)
            {
                ExternalInterface.call("redirect", API_KEY, PERMISSIONS, FB_REDIRECT_URL);
            }
        }

        private function handleGetUser(success:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            Debug.log(success + ", " + fail, this);
            if (success) dispatchEvent(new FacebookServiceEvent(FacebookServiceEvent.GET_USER_COMPLETE, success));
            else dispatchEvent(new FacebookServiceEvent(FacebookServiceEvent.GET_USER_FAIL, fail, true));
        }

        private function handleAppRequest(result:Object):void
        {
            if (postObject)
            {
                for (var i:int = 0; i < result.request_ids.length; i++)
                {
                    var requestID:String = result.request_ids[i];
                    Facebook.api("/" + requestID, handleRequestFriends); 
                }
            }
        }

        private function handleRequestFriends(success:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            if (success)
            {
                var friendID:String = success.to.id;
                Facebook.api("/" + friendID + "/feed", handleSubmitFeed, postObject, URLRequestMethod.POST);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.log(fail, this);
            }
        }

        private function handleLikes(success:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            if (success)
            {
                for (var i:int = 0; i < success.length; i++)
                {

                    Debug.log("compare " + success[i].id  + " with key: " + API_KEY, this);
                    if (success[i].id == API_KEY)
                    {

                        Debug.log("found that user liked this app!!!", this, true);
                        dispatchEvent(new FacebookServiceEvent(FacebookServiceEvent.USER_LIKES_APP, { userLikesApp:true } ));
                        return;
                    }
                }

                dispatchEvent(new FacebookServiceEvent(FacebookServiceEvent.USER_LIKES_APP, { userLikesApp:false } ));
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.log(fail, this, true);
            }
        }

        private function handleLogout(obj:*):void
        {
            currentState = _topUrl ? LOGGED_OUT : LOGGED_OUT_ON_FB;
        }

        private function handleSubmitFeed(success:Object, fail:Object):void
        {
            if (success) dispatchEvent(new FacebookServiceEvent(FacebookServiceEvent.FEED_SUBMITTED, success));
            else dispatchEvent(new FacebookServiceEvent(FacebookServiceEvent.FEED_FAIL, fail, true));
        }

        private function handleTimerEvents(e:TimerEvent):void 
        {
            switch (e.type)
            {
                case TimerEvent.TIMER :
                    _timerCount ++;
                    Debug.log("facebook init attempt " + _timerCount, this);
                    Facebook.init(API_KEY, handleLogin);
                    break;

                case TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE :
                    clearTimer();
                    dispatchEvent(new FacebookServiceEvent(FacebookServiceEvent.GET_USER_FAIL));
                    break;
            }
        }



        // accessors / mutators
        public function get currentState():String { return _currentState; }
        public function set currentState(value:String):void
        {
            if (_currentState != value)
            {
                _currentState = value;
                dispatchEvent(new FacebookServiceEvent(FacebookServiceEvent.STATE_UPDATE));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks very much
ob

Comment: Under no circumstance tell us *what* error you are getting! It would take away the fun of guessing.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: ROFL - apologies - the error i get is a fail: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://graph.facebook.com/100002210990429?access%5Ftoken=205690086123032%7C2%2EUzvN3mFr07kPAecZ7qN1Rg%5F%5F%2E3600%2E1303135200%2E1%2D100002210990429%7Cz9L%5Fc26QKCc6cs2g5FClG%5FBsoZg"]

Comment: question has been edited with error

Comment: Never post code we might solve your problem. I don't use the force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer on the facebook actionscript issues list:
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=197

> I was also trying to find a solution
>   but the only one is to publish it with
>   flash player 10

fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue.Main reason of this issue is Flash Player version.
Use **Flash Player 10+**  **FaceBookGraphApi SWC** file is compatible with Flash Player 10.
This solution is only for who are using swc from **GraphAPI_Examples_1_6_1**